# Multiple date range selection with custom views in swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calendar, custom-view

i need to develop the calendar like this attached image.i search lot of libraries.but no one is similar to this custom selection view.please some one help me.thank you..

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you use this library : [Koyomi](https://github.com/shoheiyokoyama/Koyomi)

**Select date in programmatically**

You can select specific date.

```
let today = Date()
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 7
let weekLaterDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, toDate: today)
koyomi.select(date: today, to: weekLaterDay)

// If want to select only one day. 
koyomi.select(date: today)

// If want to select multiple day.
let dates: [Date] = [date1, date2, date3]
koyomi.select(dates: dates)
```

You can also unselect available.

```
koyomi.unselect(today, to: weekLaterDay) 
// If want to unselect only one day.
koyomi.unselect(today)
// If want to unselect multiple day.
let dates: [Date] = [date1, date2, date3]
koyomi.unselect(dates: dates)

// unselect all date
koyomi.unselectAll()

// You can also call this delegate.    

extension ViewController: KoyomiDelegate {
    func koyomi(_ koyomi: Koyomi, didSelect date: Date?, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You Selected: \(date)")
    }

    func koyomi(_ koyomi: Koyomi, currentDateString dateString: String) {
        currentDateLabel.text = dateString
    }

    @objc(koyomi:shouldSelectDates:to:withPeriodLength:)
    func koyomi(_ koyomi: Koyomi, shouldSelectDates date: Date?, to toDate: Date?, withPeriodLength length: Int) -> Bool {
        if length > invalidPeriodLength {
            print("More than \(invalidPeriodLength) days are invalid period.")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

it's work for me. you can try that library.

Comment: i tried that.but i need the selection like attached image

Comment: https://github.com/weilsonwonder/WWCalendarTimeSelector
I have used this control in 2 application, Its near to similar with Android native control, so client also expecting to make similar version in both mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

#### iOS 16 - SwiftUI

You can use the SwiftUI's native `MultiDatePicker` control with supporting **noncontiguous** date selection:

```
MultiDatePicker("Dates", selection: $activityDates)
```

[image: Demo]